# LPD8806 32 rgb led 1m and raspberry pi not working

Tags: raspberry-pi, led

I have bought a 32 led strip and I'd like to connect and control it with my raspberry PI mod. B.

I am using the root user, I have /dev/spidev0.0 device, all the connections are right, I use a dual power supply with common GND.

I am testing with https://github.com/ManiacalLabs/BiblioPixel with LPD8806 driver.

I cannot succeed to control any of the led. Some of them are turned on but I have no control over them.

My wire setup is depicted here https://github.com/ManiacalLabs/BiblioPixel/wiki/SPI-Setup

Any advices?

Thank you

Comment: I'm the developer of BiblioPixel. Glad you got it working. Some strips can be a little non-standard. I just wanted to let you know that we have a forum specifically for all things BiblioPixel here: http://forum.maniacallabs.com/forumdisplay.php?fid=4
Feel free to post there any time you have related questions, or just want to show off what you made :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

The strip has a connector which "suggest" to connect the wires. You have to solder the wires at the other end to make it work!

Bye,
Massimo